# How to present R variable as a code line?

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to create a loop over a subset function, and for that I stored the subset rules in a variable (taking data from the Mat list that has all the conditions):

```
all <- paste("newdat, ", Mat[,2][j],  sep="")
all 

[1] "newdat, newdat$num_recent_claims>=2.5 & newdat$tpv_max_ratio<0.0141 & newdat$num_recent_claims>=5.5 "
```

How can I use that variable in the subset function so it will use the string as subset conditions?
Currently not working:

```
badpop <- subset(all)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Rather than storing the conditions as character strings, just store them all in a list (which will then contain logical vectors indicating satisfaction of each set of conditions). Then you can just do something like `lapply(Mat[,2][j], \`[\`)`.

Comment: thank you Thomas! just wanted to know - when you say to store them as logical vector - do you how can I convert a character string to logical? cause I'm creating those rules as string to begin with, I can't change that...

Answer (score 1):

```
all <- "newdat, newdat$num_recent_claims>=2.5 & newdat$tpv_max_ratio<0.0141 & newdat$num_recent_claims>=5.5 "
```

Need to generate a text with a code to execute it:

```
all2 <- unlist(strsplit(all, ","))
txt <- paste0 (all2[1], "[", all2[2], ", ]")

> txt
[1] "newdat[ newdat$num_recent_claims>=2.5 & newdat$tpv_max_ratio<0.0141 & newdat$num_recent_claims>=5.5 , ]"
```

And run the written code:

```
badpop <- eval(parse(text=txt))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try `eval(parse())` but keep in mind

```
fortunes::fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)

fortunes::fortune(181)

Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own future stupidity.
   -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal, answering a
      question triggered by the infamous fortune(106))
      R-help (January 2007)
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't really answer the question since it doesn't explain how OP would actually use `eval(parse(text=...))` or any alternative strategy.